# jQuery excluir o ultimo caracter digitado num input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como faz para excluir somente a ultima letra digitada num campo de input.

Todos os exemplos que encontrei é limpando todo o val do campo.

Comment: Quando? Ao clicar num botão? Ao sair do campo?

Comment: ao clicar num botão criado para essa finalidade, ao clicar chama a função que deve executar isso.

Comment: Leia sobre o método `substr` do JavaScript

Comment: acho que já que você quer controlar o que é digitado, pode usar  `regex` (http://regexr.com/) pra limitar o que pode ser informado pelo usuário

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pega o valor do input, remove o último caracter e atualiza o input.

```
var texto = $("#input_id").val();
$("#input_id").val(texto.substring(0, texto.length - 1));
```

Comment: Este foi o que atendeu melhor, mas caso eu queria mudar a função de click, para onkeydown no input, já não funciona corretamente, ele exclui o antepenultimo e o ultimo continua aparecendo, também ele exclui so a primeira vez.

Comment: @sabrinabgbc, pra deixar no `onkeydown` possivelmente você já sabe o tamanho máximo de caracteres do campo, então pode limitar com o `maxlength`

Comment: @sabrinabgbc Por favor, não mude o foco da sua pergunta. Se precisar de outra ajuda, abra uma nova pergunta. Dessa forma as coisas não ficam confusas.

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar o `slice()` ou o `substring()` para criar uma nova *string* partindo do primeiro carácter até o penúltimo e depois fazer com que esta nova *string* seja o novo valor do `input`.

**Sobre os métodos**:

O [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extrai um pedaço de uma *string* e retorna uma nova. O primeiro parâmetro é a posição inicial da "extração" e o segundo parâmetro é a posição final. Usar `-1` é equivalente à última posição, e assim por diante. [Veja mais na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

O [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) funciona de maneira parecida, com poucas diferenças, uma delas é que não é possível usar índices negativos. [Veja mais na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

**Exemplo**:

```js
$('#excluir').on('click', function (){
  var input = $('#txt');
  input.val(input.val().slice(0, -1));
});

$('#excluir2').on('click', function (){
  var input = $('#txt');
  var texto = input.val();
  input.val(texto.substring(0, texto.length - 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" value="Isso é um teste!" />
<button id="excluir">← &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
<button id="excluir2">← &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o clique do botão vai capturar o valor do input e retirar o último caracter. Após isso vai definir o novo valor para o input.

```
 $("#idBotao").click(function(){
        var input_novo_valor = $("#idInput").text().slice(0,-1); 
        $("#idInput").val(input_novo_valor);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de REGEX então vou fornecer uma resposta com o mesmo, embora [a do @jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224569/14213) já resolva perfeitamente a questão.

```js
$('#excluir').on('click', function (){
  var input = $('#txt')[0];
  input.value = input.value.replace(/.$/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" value="Isso é um teste!" />
<button id="excluir">← &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

#### Explicação

- `Pattern` : `.$` - busca o ultimo caractere
- `Replace` :  - substitui por "nada".